# Power ORing with power switch with reverse current prevention

Tags: power-supply, power, multiplexer, component-selection

Power ORing is usually done with diodes so that the power source with higher voltage is powering the load. Can these diodes be replaced by power switches such as [SiP32508](https://www.vishay.com/docs/62754/sip32508.pdf) that doesn't have output discharge function and has reverse current protection?

Update 1: More details of power source and load

We can assume the power sources are 4.2V supply and a 3.7V 1Ah Li-battery with protection. The load can be GSM module and LDO to MCU.

Comment: The answer would depend on a lot of information that you haven't provided. You should probably provide more information about the power system you have in mind, and what the load looks like.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson added these details. It'll also be great to know if there is some corner cases where power switches like one I mentioned can't be used for power ORing.

Answer (score 2):

This depends. You can build a rail-selection of almost everything.
But the specific implementation is influenced by the project needs.
Let us evaluate some example I can imagine here.

1. Your product needs to be simple or reliable. You can design an IC for everything, but nothing beats simplicity when it comes to cost effectnisness and reliability. I would suggest sticking with diodes here. But there are downsides too! You get a significant voltage drop and thereby power loss in the form of heat. You have to deal with these effects downstream so to say.
2. You build highly integrated 'top-notch' stuff where money is no concern. Let's say military or industrial. You have three different V+ rails in your System and want to switch your cards power rail upon demand? Stick with a switch like you suggested. Your time is not worth the hassle of coming up with a custom solution and cost is no objective. But why limit your feature set here? Get an IC with SMBus interface and other management stuff - check out digikey. Only your imagination is your limit these days.
3. You design a product in a consumer market and have to have an eye on cost. Let's say a mainboard selecting from either +12V external or +12V battery backup. You will have high currents and using 1$ more in chips is not that big of a deal. Go to your device. But there are devices out there which suite your requirements much better than the one you posted.
4. You are designing a high volume consumer product which needs to decide if to use +5V from USB or other input. For sure you got with Diodes. You don't care if you waste 20% of your power in heat. You don't care if there is a 0.7 V drop. You just see the 0.01$ per part in your +100k production run.
5. You are a hobbyist who wants to educate himself. I can only give this advice: Read the Datasheets of the devices that are too expensive (out of reach expensive) to use. And then carefully think about why they have the features they have. This way you will learn a lot about electronics.

Hope this gives some perspective.

Comment: Thanks @ElectronicsStudent for the answer and various perspectives. This doesn't answer my question though i.e. is swapping diodes with power switches like I mentioned feasible for power ORing.